# jsonDecode() returns strings not Lists

Tags: json, flutter, dart, codec

I'm using jsonDecode(jsonString) in dart and when used to store in a List, it returns as a string in all cases (many in the project) with no explanation.

The only thing I've been able to try is reverting versions. I've made modifications to my code with other methods, but they're the same library

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

Future verifyData() async {
  updateData();
  verifyAuthenticator();
}

Future updateData() async {

}

Future verifyAuthenticator() async {
  FlutterSecureStorage storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  List<dynamic> aJson;
  Map<String, dynamic> subJson;
  storage.read(key: "authenticators").then((str) => {
    print(jsonDecode(str).runtimeType),
    aJson = jsonDecode(str),
    aJson.forEach((dyn) => {
      subJson = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(dyn)),
      aJson.remove(dyn),
      subJson.putIfAbsent("digits", () => 6),
      subJson.putIfAbsent("period", () => 30),
      aJson.add(jsonEncode(subJson)),
      storage.write(key: "authenticators", value: jsonEncode(json))
    })
  });
}
```

I expect the aJson List to be filled and not produce an error. The actual output is an error:

```
E/flutter (18253): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

Comment: it returns Map<String, dynamic> data

Comment: How does your authenticators data (str) look like?

Comment: did you try `jsonDecode(jsonDecode(jsonString))` ? Seems like it might be JSON string of a JSON string

Comment: The Authenticator strings are [{"name":"test"},{"name":"test2"}] so it'd be a List of dynamics. I should try double decoding but this happened after I restarted my computer.